Props does not match the required types of a Next.js Page
Here is the page.tsx of my next.js website. It should take in two props. Visual studio code is not giving me any errors but when the website builds I get the following error message:
Failed to compile.
app/(Dashboard)/(practice)/practice/page.tsx
Type error: Page "app/(Dashboard)/(practice)/practice/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
"Practice" is not a valid Page export field.
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
Here is my page.tsx
import { PracticeServer } from "./Components/PracticeServer";

interface practiceProps {
  isPremium : boolean
}

export default function Practice({isPremium}: practiceProps) {
  return <PracticeServer isPremium = {isPremium} />;
}


I do not know what the error is as the console isnt giving errors. Thank you

What are you actually returning? Practice is an alias of PracticeServer, so there is some cyclic logic going on.

There is a a specific export structure in Nextjs am made to believe and the issue might be with the naming of your component or the way the component is exported.
Let's try using PracticePage to clearly indicate it's a page component and use a default export for it like the below:
import { Practice as PracticeServer } from "./Components/PracticeServer";

interface PracticeProps {
  isPhone: boolean;
  isPremium: boolean;
}

const PracticePage: React.FC<PracticeProps> = ({ isPremium, isPhone }) => {
  return <PracticeServer isPremium={isPremium} isPhone={isPhone} />;
};

export default PracticePage;


I tried what you suggested but it did not solve the build issue and the error message remained the exact same. I do appreciate your help GifftyCode.
Vince, I fixed the cyclic logic as well, but again no luck. Here is my component so far, my error message remained the same.
import { PracticeServer } from "./Components/PracticeServer";
interface practiceProps {
isPremium : boolean
}
export default function Practice({isPremium}: practiceProps) {
return ;
}

Is the file located correctly under the /pages directory or any other directory that Next.js recognizes as a valid page directory?  Is PracticeServer correctly imported and exported from its module? And also if you need to pass props like isPremium, you should use getServerSideProps.  You can read more on  Next.js Documentation on Pages and getServerSideProps

Yes. I am sure the PracticeServer is exported correctly. This page worked before perfectly, but once I created the interface and passed it props the build error started occuring. Could it be an issue with the page.tsx file not being able to take in props?

Next.js page components can certainly take props. I feel the error is likely related to how Next.js handles types for page components and their exported functions like getServerSideProps.
